# Accidentally deactivated flex slideshow on home page

Tags: javascript

I've accidentally deactivated the flex slider on the home page of the site. The content is still there--I've checked--but it's just an empty block on the home page instead of a large slider. How can I get it back? Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer can you help with this?